# Extract specific conditional data from database

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables:

1. **"business"**: fields(name, bus_id).
2. **"branch"**: fields(name, bus_id, bra_id, head_office_status).
3. **"office"**: fields(name, off_id, bra_id, main_state, sec_state).

Business is the main table which has many branches and then branches has many offices.
Now, I want to write a select query to get virtual column say `state` per business_id and my condition is as follows:

1. "(If branch has **head_office_status = 1**, then get that branch office whose **main_state != NULL** else select **sec_state**) as state.
2. (If branch doesn't has **head_office_status=1**, then get the branch whose head_office_status=0, then it's office whose **main_state != NULL** else select **sec_state**) as state.

Till now, i have written this following query:

```
SELECT business.business_id,if(main_state != NULL and head_office_status=1, 
main_state, if(sec_state != NULL and head_office_status=1,sec_state,
if(main_state !=NULL, main_state, sec_state))) as state, from business
left join branch on branch.bus_id = business.bus_id 
left join office on office.bra_id = branch.bra_id where `business_name` 
like '%';
```

But I am seeing many records per business, but I want only 1 business per record.

Comment: add limit 1 and use = in where

Comment: Its not recommended but for your problem you can use `group by  business.business_id` at the end of your query,it will pick any of the one row per business group

Comment: No group by doesn't work as group by will show 1 record per business_id but won't group based on the condition that I mentioned.